# Error rounding time to previous 15 min - Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rounding

I've developed a crude method to round timestamps to the previous 15 mins. For instance, if the timestamp is `8:10:00`, it gets rounded to `8:00:00`.

However, when it goes over 15 mins it rounds to the previous hour. For instance, if the timestamp was `8:20:00`, it gets rounded to `7:00:00` for some reason? I'll list the two examples below.

Correct Rounding:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:00:00'],                                                                                          
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

FirstTime = df['Time'].iloc[0]

def hour_rounder(t):
    return (t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0, hour=t.hour)
               -timedelta(hours=t.minute//15))

StartTime = hour_rounder(FirstTime)
StartTime = datetime.time(StartTime)

print(StartTime)
```

Out:

```
08:00:00
```

Incorrect Rounding:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:20:00'],                                                                                          
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

FirstTime = df['Time'].iloc[0]

def hour_rounder(t):
    return (t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0, hour=t.hour)
               -timedelta(hours=t.minute//15))

StartTime = hour_rounder(FirstTime)
StartTime = datetime.time(StartTime)

print(StartTime)
```

Out:

```
07:00:00
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- timedelta(hours=t.minute//15)
```

If minute is 20, then `minute // 15` equals 1, so you're subtracting one hour.

Try this instead:

```
return t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=(t.minute // 15 * 15), hour=t.hour)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.dt.floor('15min')` to round down to 15 minute invervals.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='13.141min', periods=13)})

df['prev_15'] = df.Time.dt.floor('15min')
```

#### Output:

```
                      Time             prev_15
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-01-01 00:00:00
1  2018-01-01 00:13:08.460 2018-01-01 00:00:00
2  2018-01-01 00:26:16.920 2018-01-01 00:15:00
3  2018-01-01 00:39:25.380 2018-01-01 00:30:00
4  2018-01-01 00:52:33.840 2018-01-01 00:45:00
5  2018-01-01 01:05:42.300 2018-01-01 01:00:00
6  2018-01-01 01:18:50.760 2018-01-01 01:15:00
7  2018-01-01 01:31:59.220 2018-01-01 01:30:00
8  2018-01-01 01:45:07.680 2018-01-01 01:45:00
9  2018-01-01 01:58:16.140 2018-01-01 01:45:00
10 2018-01-01 02:11:24.600 2018-01-01 02:00:00
11 2018-01-01 02:24:33.060 2018-01-01 02:15:00
12 2018-01-01 02:37:41.520 2018-01-01 02:30:00
```

---

There is also `.dt.round()` and `.dt.ceil()` if you need to get the nearest 15 minute, or the following 15 minute invterval respectively.